# Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 2

Tags: javascript, post

```html
<html>
<title>Titulo de la web</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="alternate" title="Pozolería RSS" type="application/rss+xml" href="/feed.rss" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
   

</head>

<body>
      <div class="container" id="informacion">
    <form action="procesar.php" method="post" name="frm" >
       <div class="form-row" style="display: table-caption;">


<input type="number" id="entidad" value="4006">
<br>
<input type="text" id="name" value="juan aristizabal">
<br>
<input type="number" id="cedula" value="1030547">
<br>
<input type="mail" id="mail" value="ihg@mot.com">
<br>
<input type="number" id="phone" value="1038645">
<br>
<input type="number" id="fax" value="09839678">
<br>
<input type="text" id="dir" value="calle 284n sur">
<br>
<input type="text" id="city" value="colombia">
<br>
<input type="text" id="cargo" value="secre">
<br>
<input type="text" id="description" value="juan description">



</div>
 <button type="button" id="idBoton" class="btn btn-primary" >envio</button>

</div>
</form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
 var $entidad = $('#entidad');
 var order_ent = {order_ent: $entidad.val()};
 var $name = $('#name');
 var order_name = {order_name:$name.val()};
 var $cedula = $('#cedula');
 var order_cedula = {order_cedula:$cedula.val()};
 var $mail = $('#mail');
 var order_mail = {order_mail:$mail.val()};
 var $phone = $('#phone');
 var order_phone = {phone:$phone.val()};
 var $fax = $('#fax');
 var order_fax = {order_fax:$fax.val()};
 var $dir = $('#dir');
 var order_dir = {order_dir:$dir.val()};
 var $city = $('#city');
 var order_city = {order_city:$city.val()};
 var $cargo = $('#cargo');
 var order_cargo = {order_cargo:$cargo.val()};
 var $description = $('#description');
 var order_description = {order_description:$description.val()};

 console.log(order_ent,order_name,order_cargo,order_city,order_fax,order_cedula,order_mail,order_description,order_dir,order_phone)
 $(document).ready(function(){   
 $('#idBoton').click( function(){   
 
    fetch('http://181.61.221.52:8119/operative/simplecreateticket/', {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"auth_key": "ffa07465e5af0a0f69d776e3a288dea1",
                           "entity_number" : order_ent,
                           "contact_name" :order_name,
                           "contact_phone": order_phone,
                           "description" : order_description,
                             "contact_identification": order_cedula,
                            "contact_email":  order_mail,
                             "contact_phone":  order_phone,
                              "contact_fax": order_fax,
                              "contact_address": order_dir,
                             "city_name":  order_city,
                              "contact_position_name": order_cargo,
                              "description": order_description
                         })
   })
    .then(response => response.json()) // response.json() returns a promise
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("You saved this item", response); //returns the new item along with its ID
    })
});
 });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ya me falta saber por que me sale ese eror , el codigo me sale bien y me trae los datos y tod

Comment: Seguramente lo que ocurre es que el servidor no te está respondiendo en JSON y al llamar `response.json()` no puede crear un JSON a partir de la respuesta del servidor. Debes intentar ponerle los headers para aceptar JSON y si tu controlas el servidor, asegurarte que la respuesta es de JSON